# Как из полученного на requests.get JSON получить значение по ключу?

Tags: python, json

Вот код:

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Просто текст бла-бал-бла", reply_markup=start) 
    url = str(F'https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/')
    json_str = requests.get(str(f'{url}getUpdates'))
    jsondict = json.loads(json_str.text)
    chat_id = jsondict.get("result")[0].get("update_id")
```

А вот и сам JSON как пример текста:

```
{"ok":true,"result":[{"update_id":837802896,
"message":{"message_id":607,
"from":{"id":825378476,"is_bot":false,
"first_name":"\u041d\u0438\u043a\u0438\u0442\u0430",
"last_name":"\u041a\u043e\u0434\u044b\u043c\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439",
"username":"Nikitadfgdfg","language_code":"ru"},"chat":{"id":825378476,
"first_name":"\u041d\u0438\u043a\u0438\u0442\u0430",
"last_name":"\u041a\u043e\u0434\u044b\u043c\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439",
"username":"Nikitadfgdfg",
"type":"private"},"date":1574075561,
"text":"dfgdfgdfg"}}]}
```

Как из JSON получить значение по `update_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте модуль [dpath](https://pypi.org/project/dpath/) для поиска ключей и значений в словарях любой глубины / вложенности:

```
import json
import dpath.util as dp   # pip install dpath

data = json.loads(json_str)
res = dp.values(data, "/result/**/update_id")
```

---

результат:

```
In [28]: res
Out[28]: [837802896]
```